# Can't connect to remote SQL Server hosted on ubuntu with EFCore 2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL Server from Entity Framework Core 2.

My connection string is:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DbString": "Server=example.com; Port=1433; Database=EFDB; User Id=SA; Password=FakePassword"
}
```

When I call `this._context.Database.EnsureCreated();` I get the following error:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
>   An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalEventId' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.ConfigureWarnings(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
>
>   at RestApiWithSwagger.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__4_0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in /Users/mrdisaster/dev/RestApiWithSwagger/RestApiWithSwagger/Startup.cs:line 25
>
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitSingleton(SingletonCallSite singletonCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
>
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(IServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
>   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()

What might be the problem? Any ideas?

P.S. Database tools like Management Studio, DataGrip etc. connecting successfully to this server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothting to do with SQL Server.

The relevant bit is:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalEventId' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Check that you have the correct versions of all your NuGet packages.